# RedHat Openshift on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

I have installed Openshift on AWS using installer provisioned Tool. My Container application is an VOIP server and it need to have 4 public IP addresses. So from external world other VOIP devices can connect to these 4 public IP addresses using SIP/RTP protocol messages. How can I do that? I tried setting up own VPC then install Openshift. But Openshift always install compute Node on private subnet. If I dont pass a private subnet in install script, openshft wont start installation process.
Will multus CNI can give me 4 public IP addresses for my Container?

Thanks,
Prince

Answer (score 0):

Set up your cluster using the standard IPI (installer-provisioned infrastructure) installation using the `openshift-installer`.

Then, create a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` for each of the IPs that you want: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#create-a-service-from-a-manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer
```

In your case you'll have to create 4 of these `Services` with different ports, so you'll get 4 different IPs assigned to the Load Balancer (and the Service). I do not think you need Multus or similar to achieve this.

Comment: I guess the primary concern here is that the Openshift installer provisions AWS instances in private subnet. No matter what Services you deploy in k8s to forward ports they won't be visible externally (from the outside world) until the public IPs are attached on AWS level.